# ReactJS new PropType package Throws Error

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

In a React component, I am declaring the following:

```
static propTypes = {
        data: PropTypes.shape({
            id: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
            title: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
            handle: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
            tags: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
            images: PropTypes.shape({
                edges: PropTypes.object({
                    node: PropTypes.shape({
                        src: PropTypes.string
                    })
                })
            }).isRequired
        }),
        images: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
        onClick: PropTypes.func
    }
```

The build seems to be fine with everything until it gets to `images` at which point it says `Calling PropTypes validators directly is not supported by the prop-types package. Use PropTypes.checkPropTypes() to call them.`

I don't understand the relationship between using a static object as an argument and why this error is being thrown. It's also not my code, so I'm not entirely sure why the images prop can't be flattened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant call PropTypes.object() in directly in shape. Try this one

```
images: PropTypes.shape({
     edges: PropTypes.shape({
        node: PropTypes.shape({
           src: PropTypes.string
        })
     })
}).isRequired
```

Comment: This totally worked. I'm still curious as to why PropTypes.object() was problematic. Even if I add back into the code, not embedded in anything else, it still throws an error. Thanks just the same!